# Checking column validation from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to write SQL query in such a way that the where column name should come from other table where I have mentioned the column list:

ex:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE <Column Name> = NULL
```

Now these column name is coming from another table:

```
Column Name
 Product Name
 Customer Name
```

How can I use all these columns at once to check whether they are coming as NULL.

The other table which has column name is dynamic, with dynamic I mean new column can be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF the table has dynamically added columns, then you might have to write a procedure to find the new columns..

You can find the column names of a table from the system table

```
select name 
from sys.columns 
where object_id=object_id('your_table')
```

Finally you could join the table like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable m
JOIN otherTable o ON m.id = o.id
WHERE o.<Column Name> = NULL
```

Comment: How can I add o.Column name ? I mean, there are multiple column coming from the above query.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite: This is an example.. since you have dynamic columns, you have to use a dynamic query to join with both tables